# asp.net mvc page redirected to login page after a few days

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC page which refreshes every 5 minutes. This page is used to display data only. The PC used to host this page goes days without any interaction. The page will refresh just fine for a few days, but then (on its own) this page will be redirected to the login page after 2, 4 or 5 days randomly.

Any idea as to whats going on?

I added the following attribute to Web.config for this page only as i thought maybe it was timing out while the database was running backups over night or something odd like that.

```
<location path="~/Views/Production/WIPScanStationViewer.aspx">
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="2048576"/>      
</system.web>    
</location>
```

Comment: Is the app pool recycling? Is your security cookie expiring?

Comment: The app pool is recycling. The interval is set to 1740 minutes which is 29 hours. This page will at times not be redirected to the login page for as long as 5 day though. I am not sure if the security cookie is expiring. @SteveGreene

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any form of authentication/authorization? If so, a redirect to the login screen should be the clue here. Your cookie is probably set to expire after X amount of days. If using ASPNet Identity check `Startup.cs` >> `Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)`

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider 
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user 
            // logs in. This is a security feature which is used when you 
            // change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) 
                => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
```

Since you are using forms auth the correct place to check this timeout value would be your web config. You should see something like this in the config *as long as your cookie is auto generated*

```
<!--
forms Attributes: 
name="[cookie name]" - Sets the name of the cookie used for Forms 
Authentication.
loginUrl="[url]" - Sets the URL to redirect client to for authentication.
protection="[All|None|Encryption|Validation]" - Sets the protection mode for 
data in cookie.
timeout="[minutes]" - Sets the duration of time for cookie to be valid 
(reset on each request).
path="/" - Sets the path for the cookie.
requireSSL="[true|false]" - Should the forms authentication cookie be sent 
only over SSL?
slidingExpiration="[true|false]" - Should the forms authentication cookie 
and ticket be reissued if they are about to expire?
-->
```

If your cookie is manually generated then you simply have to update your `FormsAuthenticationTicket` class to have the correct timeout value. Also note, if you have cookie setup values in your .config file but are generating a ticket/cookie manually in code somewhere, the manual generation will override the config values.

Refer to this msdn class spec for setting the timeout in code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx

Also, if the cookie is not the issue, you may want to check your session state in the web.config as well. Check this guy out here.. Pretty simple: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I am using Forms mode for authentication and not identity. i don't have a `Startup.cs` class

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag properly @Adrian

Comment: @Noahp is your ticket or cookie auto generated? If so, check your web.config file. I updated my answer to show an example with that as well

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your session cookie is expiring. Try opening that page, press F12 to open the dev. tools and go to the "Application" tab. Once there, expand the "Cookies" node and search for your session cookie. The "Expires/Max-Age" column should display the expiration date, so you'll be able to know if that's the reason behind your problem.

If that's the problem and the web browser loading that page is never getting closed, you could change the value to "Session", meaning that it will not have an expiration date, and instead of that, the cookie will expire as soon as the web browser gets closed.

You could also set the cookie to expire after X days or even months, but honestly, I'm not a big fan of cookies with a really long lifetime, especially because if the cookie gets compromised at any point, the attacker will have access to your session for as long as the cookie doesn't expire.